# How to disable freezed table column in Ant design Tables

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I wanted to keep horizontal scroll bar but don't want the freezed columns (full Name, Age & action) how to do that ? please help

```
 <Table
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={data}
    scroll={{
      x: 1300,
    }}
  />
```

codesandbox.io/s/36gkp0?file=/demo.js

Comment: Hide the full name, age & action columns?

Comment: no. currently those 3 columns are freezing while scrolling horizontal scroll bar . it should not freeze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the freezing, delete the `fixed` property from objects in `columns` array. Commented here for illustration -

```
{
    title: "Full Name",
    width: 100,
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name"
    // fixed: 'left', // delete
  },
  {
    title: "Age",
    width: 100,
    dataIndex: "age",
    key: "age",
    // fixed: "left" // delete
  },
```

[image: Edit Fixed Columns - antd@4.21.2 (forked)]